# Clicking Powerpoint Trigger while underneath another image

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm creating a small animation in Powerpoint and need to click on an image to trigger its next animation. However it also needs to be underneath another image for the animation to work. Clicking it just ends the slide so is there a way to trigger the animation while it is behind another image or must the animation just be changed so the trigger is on the image at the front?

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a rectangle atop both images, make IT the trigger, then once it's tested, give it no outline and 100% transparent fill.  It'll be invisible but will receive mouseclicks and perform the requested action.